# How to write efficient UPDATE-SELECT sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have written an sql for a table that have about 50.000.000 users. The query takes too much time than I expected that it did not finished about 23 hours.

```
UPDATE users
    SET building_id = B.id
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM buildings B
    ) AS B
    WHERE B.city          = address_city
      AND B.town          = address_town
      AND B.neighbourhood = address_neighbourhood
      AND B.street        = address_street
      AND B.no            = address_building_no
```

The idea of this sql is to that removing the building/address info from users and instead referencing it to the buildings table.

`EXPLAIN`

```
Update on users  (cost=22226900.43..22548054.14 rows=15212 width=166) 
->  Merge Join  (cost=22226900.43..22548054.14 rows=15212 width=166)
         Merge Cond: (((users.address_city)::text = (b.city)::text) AND ((users.address_town)::text = (b.town)::text) AND ((users.address_neighbourhood)::text = (b.neighbourhood)::text) AND ((users.address_street)::text = (b.street)::text) AND ((users.address_building_no)::text = (b.no)::text))
         ->  Sort  (cost=21352886.76..21401078.96 rows=96384398 width=156)
               Sort Key: users.address_city, users.address_town, users.address_neighbourhood, users.address_street, users.address_building_no
               ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..2559921.19 rows=96384398 width=156)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=874013.68..883606.86 rows=9593179 width=63)
               ->  Sort  (cost=874013.68..878810.27 rows=9593179 width=63)
                     Sort Key: b.city, b.town, b.neighbourhood, b.street, b.no
                     ->  Seq Scan on buildings b  (cost=0.00..136253.54 rows=9593179 width=63) (10 rows)
```

I don't know whether this sql uses the inner SELECT sql for each of the users or caches for transaction. Also, if it caches, does it use the indexes for the cached temp table?

I couldn't write the sql like this:

```
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM buildings B
  WHERE B.city          = users.address_city
    AND B.town          = users.address_town
    AND B.neighbourhood = users.address_neighbourhood
    AND B.street        = users.address_street
    AND B.no            = users.address_building_no
  )
```

it says that `users` cannot be accessed from the inner select. Do you have any suggestion how to access buildings in the inner sql statement.

Comment: first i wouldn't use select * instead of select the fields you really use. I would ssuggest you to use Toad or another program that can help you optimizing queries. Also you can talk to your dba to check if indexes are correct.

Comment: Can you show us an output of `EXPLAIN` for your first query?

Comment: did you check if there are table or row locks active? And please drop the subselect, you don't need it.

Comment: @Veelicus all columns are used for building. Indexes are also correct.

Comment: @FrankHeikens there were no locks on the table when executing this sql. how do you think i can update users without knowing which building_id they refer?

Comment: UPDATE users
    SET building_id = B.id
      FROM buildings B    
    WHERE B.city          = address_city
      AND B.town          = address_town
      AND B.neighbourhood = address_neighbourhood
      AND B.street        = address_street
      AND B.no            = address_building_no

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I have added the explain statement

Comment: @Veelicus it looks they have similar EXPLAIN results. I think the db instance on heroku is not powerful enough to process such data.

Comment: Do you have an index on the columns in the where condition? The database expects to update 15212 rows, does that match with you expectations? And what's the size (in MB orGB) of the tables involved?

Comment: @FrankHeikens buildings table is 2GB users table is 21 GB. We expect 50.000.000 users to be updated. Why does db expects 15212 rows?

Comment: I presume create table as  select join on those two tables and then renaming it to "users" will be faster... and will produce microsecond lock only... Of course if a table is not editable at the moment and you have enough space in temp_tablespace

Comment: @user3222580 thanks for that brilliant answer, i never thought such a trick, let me test it.

Comment: @exculuber just curious - how it goes?.. you can tell progress comparing original users table against temporary segment

Comment: @user3222580 it is 5 times faster when creating table by joining. We will proceed with your suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3222580 why don't you write as an answer

Comment: @exculuber sure - thanks! (we had horrible outage just after my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume

```
create table t as select column_list from a join b on column=column;
alter table t rename to users;
```

will be faster, and will produce microsecond lock only... 
Of course if a table is not editable at the moment and there is enough space in temp_tablespace

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but wouldn't this be (at least slightly, if not considerably) faster?

```
UPDATE users
SET building_id = B.id
FROM buildings B
WHERE B.city          = address_city
  AND B.town          = address_town
  AND B.neighbourhood = address_neighbourhood
  AND B.street        = address_street
  AND B.no            = address_building_no
```

If nothing else, it wouldn't require the `Materialize` stage as given in `EXPLAIN` above.

Comment: I did not know that we can just `FROM buildnigs B` until seeing it in comments. However, it doesn't change a bit of performance, db engine optimizes them same.

Comment: In that case its possible that you're looking at the wrong end for a solution. While at it, do both tables have appropriate indexes on the said 5 fields? If not, a Seq scan is inevitable and then any form of query re-writing is not going to make this UPDATE any faster.